# Why is $\eta$ used in $\eta$-conversion?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

In lambda calculus there are three types of reduction,

- $\alpha$-renaming
- $\beta$-reduction
- $\eta$-conversion

The use of $\eta$ in $\eta$-conversion seems rather strange to me. Since they already used $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I would expect the pattern to be continued with $\gamma$ the third Greek letter, but $\eta$ is used instead.

Why is $\eta$ used in $\eta$-conversion?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/why-is-lambda-calculus-named-after-that-specific-greek-letter-why-not-rho-calc)

Comment: On this point: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-December/087783.html - no answer there tho. "Extension" seems to come back prety often which may be related to your question, or not.

Comment: And [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433929/why-is-beta-reduction-called-beta-reduction).